# Bevel modifier is glitching my object

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I am a noobie but im really trying to learn here and this modifier is not letting me. When i apply the bevel to the object it kinds of glitches and makes a weird outline. I`ve watched tons of videos and read a lot of solutions but i can´t seem to get it right. The thing that bothers me the most is that there is two objects, the small one i managed to make it work but the big one just doesn´t want to cooperate.

[image]

Here's my file.

[image]

Comment: You have duplicate objects in the scene.

Comment: Maybe share your object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: If the problem your'e talking about is fixed by hiding Cube.001, then Gordon is on it.